# Calculate SumOfInts from Iterable

Tags: java, oop, cactoos

I need to calculate sum of `Iterable<Integer>`.

```
final Iterable<Integer> score = this.points()
final sum = new SumOfInts(...).value()
```

How can I do this using class `SumOfInts`?

Comment: where is the implementation of SumOfInts?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo [Here](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cactoos/iterable/SumOfInts.java). Inspired by the tags of the question.

Comment: You first need to convert the `Iterable<Integer>>` into a `Iterable<Scalar<Number>>`, or with Java 8: `score.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Cactoos 0.22](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos/issues/459) you can:

```
int sum = new SumOf(1, 2, 3).intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you could sum the iterable using code similar to this example:;

```
final Iterable<Integer> score = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
Optional<Integer> sum = StreamSupport.stream(score.spliterator(), false).reduce((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
System.out.println(sum.get());
```

The printed result is:

```
10
```

**Explanation:**

Iterable can be converted to a spliterator and spliterator to stream. You can then perform reductions on the stream.

As soon as you have the stream you can solve the reduction in multiple ways.

Another alternative:

```
int summed = StreamSupport.stream(score.spliterator(), false).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
System.out.println(summed);
```

This is perhaps nicer, as you get rid of the `Optional` result.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any examples of how to convert `Integer` to `Scalar<Number>` but since the `Scalar` is an interface you can do something like this.

```
public long sum() throws Exception {
    final List<Scalar<Number>> score = this.points()
            .stream()
            .map(this::toScalar)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new SumOfInts(score).value();
}

private Scalar<Number> toScalar(final Number number) {
    return () -> number;
}
```

But I bet there is a better way.